# FireFox Gmail Notifier Plugin?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I been using this plugin for year https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/173 and its stopped working for me like 5 days ago. It seems to be because of maybe the new version of firefox since it still works on my XP machine.

After looking at the comments it seems lots of people have this problem. I tried to go to this guys website but it seems to be gone.

So I am assuming this plugin is dead. I need a new one can anymore recommend me one?

Comment: The add-on works fine for me, both at home (FF 3.5.2) and at work (FF 3.0.13)... weird.

Comment: The add-ons been updated twice recently, the change notes at http://www.nexgenmedia.net/extensions/ for version 0.6.4.1, say *Login was broken for certain users due to Gmail changes* so it could well be working for you again now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [WebMail notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4490). It has support for both Gmail and Yahoo mail, among others; from the website:

> WebMail Notifier checks your webmail accounts and notifies the number of unread emails...
>   Supports: **gmail**, yahoo, hotmail, daum, naver, empas, nate and more

Comment: +1 And even Live Mail. Though I just read in the comments on the add-on page that: ... But doesn't check Gmail. Five stars if the latter is fixed.

Comment: This doesn't work with GMail currently either. The problem is a change on Google's end.

Comment: Maybe something's down at Google. It's just not possible to have broken such a basic functionality.

Comment: I've just checked my email using WebMail notifier and it worked. Please check again and see if it's not a problem on your side, thedude19

Comment: I've never been able to get Gmail to work with this add-on.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with Gmails feeds lately. The addon works for me and a few other users, while some can't get any addons working. Very strange..

Answer (score 2):

The [Gmail Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1320) plugin is working.

Comment: ya i tired it and it works. But I don't know if something is not setup or what but everytime I click on it to go to my gmail account I have to sign in. Eventhough I put automatic signin as enabled.

Comment: In the Gmail Manager preferences, for each account, there is a checkbox to "remember this password for next time." Have you checked these? If so, and it still isn't working, do you have any other add-ons dealing with passwords? Add-ons like Xmarks actually turn off Firefox's native password manager. In Preferences, Security, make sure that "Remember passwords" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Toolbar has (among other things) a GMail notifier.

While its a perfectly valid option, its not for everyone as not everyone wants all the other things that come with it. (as a side note: some of those same people [forget|ignore|are unaware of] the fact that you can disable most all of what you don't want/need and that esp. with Fx you can just add the buttons to the features that you want.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't a specific add-on. Something changed on Google's end and all mail notifiers stopped working with GMail. You'll have to wait out a fix.

Comment: Well its been like a week now. With no word from these people if it will be fiex.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Same for me... didn't experience any issue with GMail notifier.

Comment: And why would it still work on my XP machine?

Comment: @chobo2 Is **WebMail notifier** working?

Comment: I just installed it and it opens up my gmail account but it does not show me any messages saying I have a new message. It just says "Gmail : not checked".

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable offline Gmail or installed Google Gears? The plugin is still working for me in browsers where I have no google gears enabled but not in the others with google gears enabled AND offline gmail activated.

Comment: I don't think I have it enabled for offline nor do I have Google gears.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Gmail Notifier](http://www.gmailnotifier.com/), it uses IMAP support multiple accounts and many more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using that add-on with a Google Apps account, and am having no problems. One thing you can do to try to track down the error is look at Gmail Notifier's log file. This should log any errors it's getting, and give a clue as to what may be causing the error. Find the log by right-clicking the GMail icon, then click `Preferences`, on the new window that appears click the `Console` button at the bottom.

This should say where its been having problems (whether it can  connect to the servers, whether there've been password problems, etc).