# Gmail Notifier's "mailto" feature is not working on Windows XP SP3 + Firefox 3.5.5

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-notifier

The main reason I installed Gmail Notifier was so I could use Gmail to send messages when I click on a "mailto" link in my browser. I've installed the software and made sure the options are set correctly, but this feature simply doesn't work.

I still get the same ol' Outlook "New Mail Message" window when I click a "mailto" link.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work? I'm using Windows XP SP3, and my default browser is Firefox 3.5.5 (I do have IE8 installed).

Note: this is not a duplicate of [FireFox Gmail Notifier Plugin?](https://superuser.com/questions/44736/firefox-gmail-notifier-plugin) because my problem is only with the "mailto" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Toolbar provides the mailto: redirection.
Try that first!

More info [here](http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34800).

Comment: +1 thank you! You've solved several of my problems with this answer. I was using Googlebar Lite and a separate AutoFill extension, because, when I first switched from IE to FF a few versions ago, there was no FF version of Googlebar. Anyway, this is great.

Comment: I am new here, it is the first accepted answer I got in this community, I am glad that I was helpful. Take care!

Answer (score 2):

To do that in Firefox, you don't need to use addons or plugins. Just go to Firefox `Tools -> Options` and in the `Applications` tab, select `"Use GoogleMail"` as your default `mailto` action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways to integrate webmail into the entire system, including the browser, is by installing [Affixa](http://www.affixa.com/Default.aspx).  You'll even be able to email your MS Office documents to anyone without having Outlook or another mail client installed on your machine!  Give it a try, it's free :)

Comment: Besides that this program might not be the answer the OP asked for, it does what he wants and is definitely not spam, perhaps just poorly worded.